# increament the value of arraylist element by one java

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

I have one dimensional array list and I need to add one to the arraylist element each step if a certain condition was satisfied this is equavelent for example to number[i]=+1; I am applying the following loop

```
For(int i=0;i<Number;i++)
{if certain condition was met then
Array_list_element.get(i)=Array_list_element.get(i)+1;
else perform another action}
```

but how I can do this Array_list_element.get(i)=Array_list_element.get(i)+1;
I am a little confused if I did the following code

```
Array_list_element.get(i).add(1)
```

will the value of Array_list_element.get(i) will be always one or the one will be added at each step the condition is satified how you suggest to do this

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried this code ?  What was the problem are you facing ? which `Array` class are you referrning to is it `java.lang.reflect.Array` ?

Comment: I am using Integer array list I am a little confused if I used add method does the existing value of the element will be replaced or will be increamented

Comment: So increment each and every element by 1 if a condition is met? Or increment only one of the elements and then perform the same condition check for the rest?

Comment: I will update the post to clarify this sorry for the confusion

Comment: Where is the check performed? In the loop or outside the loop? It makes a difference. Also post your full code (including the check and loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will increment the value of each element.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i ++) {
    int oldVal = arrayList.get(i);
    int newVal = oldVal + 1;
    arrayList.set(i, newVal);
}
```

You just need to now put your conditional check either around the for loop if you want every element to increase. Or if you want specific elements to increase then you need to possibly perform a check on the oldVal if that is what you are basing it on.

**Edit:** So looks like you want the check inside the for loop so here is an example.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i ++) {
    int oldVal = arrayList.get(i);
    if (oldVal == 2) {
        int newVal = oldVal + 1;
        arrayList.set(i, newVal);
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```